# How do I make Google Chrome to open two websites from a single shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, shortcuts

and(if possible) on a computer where Google Chrome is not set as default internet browser

Comment: Via what? A shortcut? What OS?

Comment: give more information about your question..shortcut?

Comment: sorry, Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough information.  But if I assume you are working with Windows, you can create a shortcut pointing to the Chrome EXE file and specify which sites you want to launch at startup inside of the shortcut.  For example (if you installed Chrome into the default directory for Windows), create a shortcut that points to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.Exe"
```

Once it is created, go back and edit the properties of that shortcut.  Add the sites you want to connect to automatically each time the shortcut is run to the end of the **TARGET** line, so that the **TARGET** line looks something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.Exe" http://www.google.com http://stackexchange.com
```

Now when you launch that shortcut, each site will come up automatically

Comment: fantastic! I knew it was simnple like that, thanks a lot